# Huge file when exporting iPhoto slideshow

Tags: photos.app

I am creating a slideshow in iPhoto, my slideshow contains about 70 images, each image is about 10MB. When selecting Export to 1080p, it says that it needs more than 20GB of disk space to export. This is insane. My slideshow is using Vintage Prints theme and a 7-minute music file.

Is there something wrong here? I searched on the internet for the solution but it just mentioned the issue, no solution for this at all. Or maybe this is normal? (which I don't really think so)

**Update:**

I took the warning seriously and tried to export the slideshow to an external 1TB hard disk (my Mac disk only had 10GB or less). The export was extremely slow, I let it run overnight and guess what I saw in the final result? The exported video was just only 308MB. Hell, I guess there is a bug in the iPhoto and they are doing crazy buffering while exporting. So, the "final exported file" is not as big as its warning, but you still need to have enough space to run the export function.

Comment: are you exporting in original format or converting ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I did not convert anything so I assume the answer is "original format" :)

Comment: Have you considered using Photos instead of iPhoto?

Comment: Hey @JBis, oh man, I completely forgot that I have an application called Photos on my Mac (even though I used it several times before, just not for creating slideshow). Thanks a lot for reminding me of this. Poor my old memory!!

Answer (score 1):

Your best option I think is to reduce the size of your images. This can be done with Preview but is doesn't run in batch mode. There are third party apps like [Pixillion](https://www.nchsoftware.com/software/thanks.html?software=Pixillion&appname=Pixillion%20Image%20Converter&version=6.01MAC&base=imageconverter&domain=nchsoftware&buyoffer=pixillion&pclass=plus&rgst=0&svar=LLIBSucaoffLLIBNagaltrunsoff&instby=dl&iid=&help=0) that will change your image to a different format or just reduce the quality slightly resulting in a much smaller image. Pixillion has a trail period so you can play with it and see if it works for you. It also appears to have a batch mode option. I saw a 50% reduction by degrading quality by a slight amount. You should play with this to see when you start noticing degradation in the image. See Pixillion panes below.

[image]

After pressing the "Compression Settings" button you get the pane shown below.

[image]

Another option is the App [Squash](https://www.realmacsoftware.com/squash/). I don't know how this pwrforms but it sounds like it may do what you want. Developers do not offer a free trail period so its $15 and cross your fingers it helps you.

The last option is the one I mentioned earlier. In preview you can go to the  tools menu and click on Adjust size as shown below.

[image]

When you click on adjust size you get a pane that looks like the image shown below. As you can see you can adjust the image size or the resolution. You can play with these parameters to find the best values.

[image]